# Can I do my freelancing software development during Aitkaf in ramdan?

Tags: ramadan

Assalam -o- Alaikum, its the first time that i have planned to go for aitkaf in this ramzan. I am doing studying before that so that i can know what is aitkaf and what are its dos/dont's. I cannot find one thing though, is it permissible to do some freelancing work on my laptop during aitkaf, kindly guide me about this. I do software development and i currently have ongoing projects and secondly if i take a ten days holiday, it could hurt my online stats. Jazak Allah.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Walaikum salam wa rahamatullahi wa barakatuhu,

No it is not possible. Objective of Aitikaaf is to cut off from the worldly affairs and focus on worship.

Comment: Kindly share some references from hadith or Quran.

Comment: Masjids are built for the purpose of worship. It is not one of the functions of masjid to be a place of buying and selling. Abu Hurairah (may Allah be pleased with him) reported that the Messenger of Allah said,

"If you see someone buy or sell in the Masjid, then say, 'May Allah not make your trade profitable." - [At-Tirmidhi - Hasan]

Comment: thank you very much, you made it easy for me. Jazak Allah

Comment: BarakAllahu Feekum